# Implement bubble sort by ARM assembly

Tags: io, arm, bubble-sort

I hope to use ARM to compile the function of my raspberry pie terminal: enter a number of Numbers, then make bubble sort in the program, and output the sorted result.
Compile and link no problem, but the screen appears "Illegal instruction" when executing the target file(ARM GNU style)

```
 .globl _start
 _start:
     mov r4,#0
     ldr r6,=src
     add r6,r6,#len
outer:
     ldr r1,=src

inner:
     ldr r2,[r1]
     ldr r3,[r1,#4]
     cmp r2,r3
     strgt r3,[r1]
     Strgt r2,[r1,#4]
     add r1,r1,#4
     cmp r1,r6
     blt inner

     add r4,r4,#4
     cmp r4,#len
     suble r6,r6,#4
     ble outer

stop:
    mov r0,#0x18
    ldr r1,=0x20026
    swi 0x123456


.section .data
src:
.long 2,4,10,8,14,1,20

.equ len, 4
```

Comment: You should be able to do exactly the same things on ARM you can do on x86.  Could you show us a code example of a thing you can do with x86 but not ARM?

Comment: while the ARM assembly *is* different, I highly doubt the ARM ubuntu kernel has no system API for `read/write` and STDIN/STDOUT support, that would be not a UNIX-like OS any more... you just need to find correct docs, how to call the system services from assembly. Oh wait, the ubuntu is on your development VM, not on Pi? Then it depends what OS has the Pi, or if you are going without OS... you still need either target OS API, or learn how to control the HW connected to Pi.

Comment: x86 assembly cannot on an os directly access terminal input or output either, you have to ask the operating system. which obviously both platforms have support for.

Comment: where do you have this virtual machine?  do you mean you have some operating system on the pi then ubuntu in another operating system on top of that like raspian then ubuntu in a vm?  why the extra layer?  not that it changes anything.

Comment: @Gaurav: There's no evidence at all the OP is using scanf with a bogus format string.  Doesn't looks like a duplicate to me, just another vaguely titled question.

Comment: Are you running a virtual machine on the RPi?  Is it an ARM VM, or is it an x86 Ubuntu VM?  Not much to do with your real question, but I don't understand why you're using a VM here or what that has to do with anything.

Comment: @fuz This is obviously two different styles of assembly language

Comment: @PeterCordes My RPi runs a dedicated system, which is an independent Linux system. I use two different methods to execute my target file.The first is to cross-compile the ".s "file on my PC (Windows 8) virtual machine (Linux), and then execute it on my raspberry pie.The other is to compile the ".s "file directly on the raspberry pie and execute it.

Comment: @ZeusChen And? Both are still able to do the same kind of operations, just in different ways. I don't quite understand what you are missing, which is why I asked for an example.

Comment: So the problem is nothing to do with either method of building, you just don't know how to invoke Linux's `sys_read` and `sys_write` system calls with the SWI instruction?

Comment: @PeterCordes That's true,I don't know.

Comment: @fuz I'm very sorry that I didn't explain the problem clearly.As PeterCordes said,I just don't know how to invoke Linux's sys_read and sys_write system calls with the SWI instruction.

Comment: @ZeusChen Then why don't you say that directly instead of making some nebulous claims? We've been discussing for a day now just to get to your actual question which you could have posted directly into the question.

Comment: @fuz I want to use ARM assembly to implement bubble sort: enter a string of Numbers ,then sort them in the program, and output the results of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I can use ARM assembler to implement bubble sort on my Raspberry pie without input character, the code is as follows：

```
.section .text
.global _start

_start: 
    mov r2,#10  @The number of characters output
    mov r4,r2   
    b loop      @Enter the first cycle
loop:
    mov r1,pc   @Point to the first position of the string
    ldr r1,=str 
    sub r4,r4,#1
    cmp r4,#0   @R4 is compared to 0, and if r4 is equal to 0, 
                @end up,print result 
                @greater than it goes into the second cycle
    beq stop    
    mov r5,#0   
    b loop1     @The entrance to the second cycle
    b loop


loop1:

    ldrb r3,[r1]    @R1 is pointing to the memory address of the value of 
                    @the assignment to the r3 register
    ldrb r6,[r1,#1] 
    cmp r3,r6       @r3 r6 compared
    strgtb r3,[r1,#1]   @If greater than r6, their values are exchanged
    strgtb r6,[r1]
    add r1,r1,#1        @R1 points to the next character
    add r5,r5,#1        
    cmp r5,r4       @r5 r4 compared
    bne loop1       @r5<r4 next loop1
    b loop          @r5=r4，Jump out of the second cycle and return to the 
                    @first cycle
stop:
    @printf str
    add r2,r2,#1
    mov r0,#0x1
    mov r1,pc
    ldr r1,=str
    mov r7,#0x4
    svc 1

    @exit
    mov r0,#0x0
    mov r7,#0x1
    svc 1
@Define data segment
.data
str:
.ascii "7543216890\n"
```

The result is:0123456789[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxCn3.jpg)